# Can I have two 'AND' SQL Operators in the same syntax?

Tags: wordpress

This works:

```
[pods name="conference_2019" where="(country.name = 'United States') AND (recommended.meta_value = '1')" orderby="start_date.meta_value DESC" template="Conference Archive"]
```

This does not:

```
[pods name="conference_2019" where="(country.name = 'United States') AND (start_date.meta_value LIKE '2019-05%')" AND (recommended.meta_value = '1')" orderby="start_date.meta_value DESC" template="Conference Archive"]
```

The difference is that syntax that **does not work** has two 'AND' operators. I have tried various ways to try and merge them but it doesn't work for me.

I'm sure this is a pretty simple thing - can anyone pls jump in and help?

Thanks!!

Comment: What language is this? It's not SQL.

Comment: I don't know what language that is, but from the universal logic that an opening (or closing) quote needs a matching closing (or opening) quote, I'd guess you have one double quote too much, the one at the end of `LIKE '2019-05%')"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you might have some missing or extra quotes in there. 
[pods name="conference_2019" where="(country.name = 'United States') AND (start_date.meta_value LIKE '2019-05%')" AND (recommended.meta_value = '1')" orderby="start_date.meta_value DESC" template="Conference Archive"]

there are quotes around the first and second clause “country name = US AND start_date...” AND recommended...

you may want to try again with each clause individually wrapped in quotes. `“name=...” AND “start_date=...” AND “recommended=...”`

You can pair them together with parens if execution order matters, eg.:

`WHERE (name='...' AND start_date='...') AND recommended='...'`

Comment: Parens don't affect execution order.

Comment: It should affect logical comparison, not execution order. ```true AND false OR true``` should be different than ```true AND (false OR true)```

Comment: As I still don't know of what language we're talking about here, I might be wrong here, but those fancy `“` and `”` quotes are likely to cause trouble. At least they'd do in any language I can think of now. Better use plain old `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much!

The code was a WordPress shortcode which I guess uses SQL Syntax?

Anyways - FWIW here is what works:

```
[pods name="conference_2019" where="(country.name = 'United States' AND recommended.meta_value = '1' AND start_date.meta_value LIKE '2019-05%')" orderby="start_date.meta_value DESC" template="Conference Archive"]
```

Seems like the answer is to merge 'AND' in a single ()

Comment: No, the parens are irrelevant. The answer is to remove the extra `"` you had.